# Android keyboard : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: android

Strangely my small "keyboard" app throws such error:

```
12-09 21:38:20.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service AKeyboard.com.rob.AKeyboard: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AKeyboard.com.rob.AKeyboard in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/AKeyboard.com.rob-2.apk]
```

```
package AКeyboard.com.rob;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class main extends InputMethodService 
implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {


    private LinearLayout mInputView;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }


    @Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        return mInputView;
    }

. . .
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` is apparently expecting to find a class called `AKeyboard.com.rob.AKeyboard`, but you've defined your class as `main` (fully qualified as `AKeyboard.com.rob.main`). Either rename the class or change your manifest.